# Python dictionary holding reference to a global variable

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, variables

I feel like I am trying to go against the Zen of Python with this, but I have a situation like that:

```
my_var = False
my_var_2 = True

my_dict = {
    '1': {'a': my_var, 'b': my_var_2}
     .
     .
    'n': {...}
}
```

Now, what I would like to do, is have my_dict['1'] values **keep links to the globally declared my_var and my_var_2**, so that when I update my_dict['1']['a'] or my_dict['1']['b'], my_var and my_var_2 also get updated. Obviously, that is not happening with the current code in place, but I was wondering if it was possible to arrive at that effect via some creative use of the language.

Why am I trying to do that? I would like my_dict values to be handles for the my_var and my_var_2, used in a generic function working on on my_dict key by key, and updating these variables declared outside of the dict (I cannot call the variables by names due to level of genericity of the function though).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to overload the index operator.
For the above use case it is sufficient to overload the value setter `__setitem__` but perhaps you would need also `__getitem__`:

```
my_var_2 = True
my_var = False

class GlobalMap:
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        global my_var, my_var_2
        if key == "a":
            my_var = value
        elif key == "b":
            my_var_2 = value
        else:
            raise Exception('invalid global {}'.format(key))


my_dict = {
    '1': GlobalMap(),
}

my_dict['1']['a'] = True
```